# FireMonkey Android: raised exception class EJNIException with message 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (XX ... XX) ends beyond length X

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have 2 `TNumberBox` controls in my page, and their property changes are as follows:

MaxValue : 1E9
DecimalDigits: 2
Text: 0.00
KeyBoardType: DecimalNumberpad

Also, in both boxes, I call `SelectAll()` in the `OnClick` event, eg:

```pascal
procedure TfrmExpenseClaim.numTaxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  numTax.SelectAll;
end;
```

I also have a `TComboBox` on the page. I can enter a value on the first `TNumberBox` and then, based on a certain `TComboBox` value, the second `TNumberBox` will get updated.  Also, I can update the second `TNumberBox` value manually, which does not have an effect on the first `TNumberBox`.

First Number Box value : 110
Combo Box value : 10% tax
Second `TNumberBox` value gets updated as 10 = `( NumberBox1.Value – ( NumberBox1.Value / ( 1 + 10/ 100))`

The calculations work fine.

The problem is, if I change the second `TNumberBox` value manually, and then quickly change the `TComboBox` value again and again, and then select the second `TNumberBox`, it will display the following error:

> Project ExpenseClaims.apk raised exception class EJNIException with message 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (6 ... 6) ends beyond length 4'.

The `setSpan (6 … 6)` changes, as sometimes it displays `(5 … 5)` and `(4 … 4)`. Afterwards, most of the time when I select that second `TNumberBox`, I will get that error and the values also get updated incorrectly.

The only way to recover after getting this error is to close the app and open it again.

I tried to capture that error in code, but could not as it comes outside of the Delphi code that I have written.

Is this a known error?  If so, what can I do to fix it?

```pascal
type
  TfrmExpenseClaim = class(TForm)
    numTax: TNumberBox;  
    numInclTax: TNumberBox;  
    cmbTaxCategory: TComboBox;
    procedure numInclTaxClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure numTaxClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure numInclTaxChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cmbTaxCategoryChange(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FTaxDetailsList : TTaxDetailsList;
    procedure CalculateTax;
  end;

...

procedure TfrmExpenseClaim.cmbTaxCategoryChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CalculateTax;
end;

procedure TfrmExpenseClaim.numInclTaxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cmbTaxCategory.Selected.Text <> '' then
  begin
    CalculateTax;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmExpenseClaim.numInclTaxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  numInclTax.SelectAll;
end;

procedure TfrmExpenseClaim.numTaxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //This is where the problem occur as I think, but not in delphi code
  numTax.SelectAll;
end;

procedure TfrmExpenseClaim.CalculateTax;
var
  I: Integer;
var
  dPriceEx, dTaxVal: Double;
begin
  dPriceEx := 0.00;
  for I := 0 to FTaxDetailsList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // Filling up the FTaxDetailsList work fine which is done via a API call
    if (cmbTaxCategory.Selected.Text = FTaxDetailsList[I].RateTitle) then
    begin
      if FTaxDetailsList[I].TaxRate = 0.00 then
      begin
        numTax.Value := 0.00;
      end
      else
      begin
        dPriceEx := numInclTax.Value / (1 + FTaxDetailsList[I].TaxRate / 100);
        dTaxVal := numInclTax.Value;
        numTax.Value := dTaxVal - dPriceEx;
        // Example 1 : numInclTax.Value is 110.00 and the FTaxDetailsList[I].TaxRate is 10 (10%). Therefore the numTax.Value should be 10.00;
        // Example 2 : numInclTax.Value is 110.00 and the FTaxDetailsList[I].TaxRate is 0 (0%). Therefore the numTax.Value should be 0.00;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The problem won't occur in the first instance. Maybe not until the 5th or 6th instance. But it will occur after a few quick changes.

How to produce:

First set of Steps:

1. Enter a value to `numInclTax.Value` (eg : 115.00)
2. By default, the `cmbTaxCategory` is set to 15% GST. Meaning 15% tax rate.
3. It will calculate the `numTax.Value` based on the `TfrmExpenseClaim.CalculateTax` code to 15.00

This works fine.

Second set of Steps:

1. Then change the `cmbTaxCategory` option to Zero based tax (which is no tax)
2. It will calculate the `numTax.Value` based on the `TfrmExpenseClaim.CalculateTax` code to 0

Works fine.

Third set of Steps:

1. Then update the `numTax.Value` by swapping across the Number box. It will either increase or reduce the `numTax.Value` based on the direction you swap (I never went to minus values)
2. Then again change the `cmbTaxCategory` option, again it should calculate the values.
3. Then `numTax.Value` by swapping across the Number box again.

At some point, by repeating the Third set of Steps again and again, on the 3rd step as soon as you select the `numTax.Value` the error will occur.

I was only able to replicate this on Android. And I think it might be something to do with swapping across the number box. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing all of the relevant code for how the `TNumberBox` and `TComboBox` controls update each other, and also show the exact user input values that cause the error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , I have added the code to the description and the steps to produce it..

Comment: I have this problem too. Delphi 10.3.3.

Don't know how to create a reproducible example.